# Transfer a c++ object between cython and pybind11 using python capsules

Tags: python, c++, cython, pybind11

I have two c++ libraries that expose python API but using two different frameworks(pybind11 and cython). I need to transfer an object between them (both ways) using python capsules. Since cython and pybind11 use the python capsules different ways, is it even possible to make it work?

I have library A that defines a class `Foo` and exposes it with pybind11 to python. Library B exposes its API using cython. LibB owns a `shared_ptr<Foo>` which is a member of one of LibB's classes, say - `Bar`.

Bar returns the `shared_ptr<Foo>` member as a `PyCapsule` which I capture in pybind11 of the `Foo` class. I'm unpacking the `shared_ptr<Foo>` from the capsule, returning it to python and the user can operate on this object in python using pybind11 bindings for `Foo`.

Then I need to put it back in a capsule in pybind11 and return back to `Bar`.

Bar's python API operates on `PyObject` and `PyCapsule` because cython allows that. pybind11 and thus Foo's API does not accept those types and I'm forced to use `pybind11::object` and `pybind11::capsule`.

Everything works fine until the moment when I'm trying to use the `pybind11::capsule` created in pybind11, inside a cython method of class `Bar` which expects a `PyCapsule*`.

The `shared_ptr<Foo>` inside the `pybind11::capsule` is corrupted and my app crashes.

Has anyone tried to make those 2 libs talk to each other?

libA -> class Foo

```
namespace foo{
    class Foo {
    public:
        void foo() {...}
    }
}
```

libB -> class Bar

```
namespace bar {
    class Bar {
    public:
        PyObject* get_foo() {
            const char * capsule_name = "foo_in_capsule";
            return PyCapsule_New(&m_foo, capsule_name, nullptr);
        }

        static Bar fooToBar(PyObject * capsule) {
            void * foo_ptr = PyCapsule_GetPointer(capsule, "foo_in_capsule");
            auto foo  = static_cast<std::shared_ptr<foo::Foo>*>(foo_ptr);
            // here the shared_ptr is corrupted (garbage numbers returned for use_count() and get() )
            std::cout << "checking the capsule: " << foo->use_count() << " " << foo->get() << std::endl

            Bar b;
            b.m_foo = *foo; //this is what I would like to get
            return b;
        }

        std::shared_ptr<Foo> m_foo;
    };
}
```

pybind11 for Foo

```
void regclass_foo_Foo(py::module m)
{
    py::class_<foo::Foo, std::shared_ptr<foo::Foo>> foo(m, "Foo");
    foo.def("foo", &foo::Foo::foo);
    foo.def_static("from_capsule", [](py::object* capsule) {
        auto* pycapsule_ptr = capsule->ptr();
        auto* foo_ptr = reinterpret_cast<std::shared_ptr<foo::Foo>*>(PyCapsule_GetPointer(pycapsule_ptr, "foo_in_capsule"));
        return *foo_ptr;
    });
    foo.def_static("to_capsule", [](std::shared_ptr<foo::Foo>& foo_from_python) {
        auto pybind_capsule = py::capsule(&foo_from_python, "foo_in_capsule", nullptr);
        return pybind_capsule;
    });
}
```

cython for Bar

```
cdef extern from "bar.hpp" namespace "bar":
    cdef cppclass Bar:
        object get_foo() except +

def foo_to_bar(capsule):
    b = C.fooToBar(capsule)
    return b
```

putting it all together in python

```
from bar import Bar, foo_to_bar
from foo import Foo

bar = Bar(... some arguments ...)
capsule1 = bar.get_foo()

foo_from_capsule = Foo.from_capsule(capsule1)

// this is the important part - need to operate on foo using its python api
print("checking if foo works", foo_from_capsule.foo())
// and use it to create another bar object with a (possibly) modified foo object
capsule2 = Foo.to_capsule(foo_from_capsule)

bar2 = foo_to_bar(capsule2)
```

Comment: My guess is that `PyCapsule` is the wrong way to go - it's designed to hold a pointer rather than a shared pointer so I'd guess you're initializing two `shared_ptr`s from the same C pointer. In Cython you can make a class `public` which provides a .h file containing the underlying C struct. That seems like the place I'd start...

Comment: Regarding the [mre] - I don't think you necessarily have to include the Python capsule bit of it (since I think that's likely to lead to answers trying to fix capsules rather than do it the right way) but you do need to at least show a minimal Cython and Pybind wrapper I think

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I've added some code snippets showing the situation I'm in. Just FYI, I can modify both libs because they are both developed in my company. The thing is that I have to operate on a shared_ptr<Foo> rather than on Foo objects/pointers directly. That's because of how libA is built.

Please have a look again and let me know if there's anything that can be done here. I'm stuck with the `static Bar fooToBar(PyObject * capsule)` method beacuse I'm getting a segfault in runtime here.

Comment: I cannot run your code, but one obvious problem is to take a raw pointer from m_foo. instead you could copy construct a shared pointer from it with new (and free it when capsule is destructed). Right now the pointer can become dangling ( and this is probably what happens).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's too many unfinished details in your code for me to even test your `PyCapsule` version. My view is that the issue is with the lifetime of the shared pointers - your capsule points to a shared pointer that's lifetime is tied to the `Bar` it's in. However, the capsule may outlive that. You should probably be creating a new `shared_ptr<Foo>*` (with `new`), pointing to that in your capsule, and defining a destructor (for the capsule) to delete it.

---

An outline of an alternative approach that I think should work better is as follows:

Write your classes purely in terms of C++ types, so `get_foo` and `foo_to_bar` just take/return `shared_ptr<Foo>`.

Define `PyBar` as a proper Cython class, rather than using capsules:

```
cdef public class PyBar [object PyBarStruct, type PyBarType]:
    cdef shared_ptr[Bar] ptr

cdef public PyBar PyBar_from_shared_ptr(shared_ptr[Bar] b):
    cdef PyBar x = PyBar()
    x.ptr = b
    return x
```

This generates a header file containing definitions of `PyBarStruct` and `PyBarType` (you probably don't need the latter). I also define a basic module-level function to  create a `PyBar` from a shared pointer (and make that public as well, so it appears in the header too).

Then use PyBind11 to define [a custom type-caster](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/cast/custom.html) to/from `shared_ptr<Bar>`. `load` would be something like:

```
bool load(handle src, bool) {
        auto bar_mod = py::import("bar");
        auto bar_type = py::getattr(bar_mod,"Bar");
        if (!py::isinstance(src,bar_type)) {
            return false;
        }

        // now cast to my PyBarStruct
        auto ptr = reinterpret_cast<PyBarStruct*>(src.ptr());

        value  = ptr->ptr; // access the shared_ptr of the struct
    }
```

while the C++ to Python caster would be something like

```
 static handle cast(std::shared_ptr<Bar> src, return_value_policy /* policy */, handle /* parent */) {
     auto bar_mod = py::import("bar"); // See note...
     return PyBar_from_shared_ptr(src);
 }
```

I've ensured to include `py::import("bar")` in both functions because I don't think it's safe to use the Cython-defined functions until the module has been imported somewhere and importing it in the casters does ensure that.

This code is untested so almost certainly has errors, but should give a cleaner approach than `PyCapsule`.

Comment: It was the object lifetime problem indeed. I've created a shared_ptr on the heap in `to_capsule` binding, put it in the capsule with a custom destructor which casts the `PyObject*` to `shared_ptr<foo::Foo>*` and deletes it. Worked like a charm, thank you!

BTW. I was trying to paste the code here, but it's not possible to add code blocks in the comments, only in questions and answers...